# TypeLite generate enums decorated with attributes only

Tags: c#, typescript

Is it possible in TypeLite to generate only those enum values which are decorated with appropriate attributes only. In C# I have:

```
public enum MyType : int
{
    [AllowType]
    General = 0,

    CustomerCategory = 1,

    [AllowType]
    Company = 2,
}
```

and in TypeScript I need:

```
export enum AsyncCommandState {
    General = 0,
    Company = 2
}
```

Comment: What is it generating now?

Comment: it generates all enums General, CustomerCategory, Company - i need to omit CustomerCategory because this one is not decorated with AllowType attribute in C#